# delete duplicate columns in python list

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I have the following list as example:

```
ls=[
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6],
    ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    ['r', 's' ,'t', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
]
```

And I want to delete duplicate elements such that once a duplicate is detected, its index must be used to delete all the element having this index in the other rows. The result of example must be:

```
[
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6],
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g'],
['r', 't', 'v', 'w', 'z']
]
```

I wrote the following code:

```
#Helping function to delete the elements of col_index from all rows
def delete_col(l, col_index):
    for sl in l:
        del sl[col_index]

#To delete the duplicates.
def list_without_columns_duplicates(l):
    i=0
    j=1
    while i<len(l):
        while j<len(l[0]):
            if l[i][j]==l[i][j-1]:
                delete_col(l, j)
            j+=1
        i+=1
```

However, I found two problems with when I run this code: (1) It considers the duplicates of the first row only, and (2) It delete only the first duplication and needs multiple runs to delete all the other duplicates. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your input lists don't have the same length. What to do if the indeces are missing in the other lists?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, Thanks for your answer. However, using ```set(i)``` considers each row separately from other rows and thus it will not give the appropriate result I want

Comment: @schwobaseggl, I edited the lists and they have now the same length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
from itertools import chain

ls = [
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6],
    ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    ['r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
]


def find_duplicated_indexes(l):

    seen = set()
    for i, e in enumerate(l):
        if e not in seen:
            seen.add(e)
        else:
            yield i


indexes = set(chain.from_iterable(find_duplicated_indexes(l) for l in ls))
result = [[e for i, e in enumerate(l) if i not in indexes] for l in ls]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 3, 4, 5, 6], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g'], ['r', 't', 'v', 'w', 'z']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of indices to avoid and then filter the sublists of `ls`:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
ls = [[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6], ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']]
inds = {l for j in ls for _, i in gb(list(enumerate(j)), key=lambda x:x[-1]) for l in [a for a, _ in list(i)[1:]]}
r = [[a for i, a in enumerate(b) if i not in inds] for b in ls]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3, 4, 5, 6], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g'], ['r', 't', 'v', 'w', 'z']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more elegant solution if you can use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

ls=[
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6],
    ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    ['r', 's' ,'t', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
]

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ls[0], 'A': ls[1], 'B': ls[2]})

print(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A'], keep='first'))
```

Output:

```
   id  A  B
0   1  a  r
2   3  b  t
4   4  c  v
5   5  d  w
6   5  e  x
7   5  f  y
8   6  g  z
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution that I've developed.

```
new_ls = []
for element in ls:
    inside_list = []
    for el in element:
        if el in inside_list:
            continue
        inside_list.append(el)
    new_ls.append(inside_list)

ls = new_ls
```

What it does is just simply creating a fresh new array and appends each of the element inside the nested list, but skips one if the element is already in the nested list!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the

> set method, set will allow only unique values.

Iterate over the list of lists in your case like below and apply set and convert it into the list. the

> new_list contains the output as you required.

```
 new_list = [] 
 for l in ls:
     new_list.append(list(set(l)))

 print(new_list)
```